# Can you use state or call other methods inside the getInitialProps() method in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do this but it's not working:

```
static async getInitialProps({ req, res, query }) {

    // Call another method in the component
    const foo = this.foo();

    // Use the component's state here
    const foobar = [...foo, ...this.state.bar];

}
```

This is just pseudo code, in my actual use case I'm trying to build a URL to send an AJAX request. This URL is built by a method in my component which is also called by the client-side rendering. So I want to keep it in the same place and use it for both the initial rendering and the subsequent client-side rendering. But I can't call that method `this.buildURL()` from inside `getInitialProps`. I also can't use state in that function, how to go about this or a workaround?

Comment: You're misusing it. There's no state at this point. The component isn't initialized yet. That's why the method is static.

Comment: @estus not sure what you mean, I'm able to use the response just fine if I hard code the url instead of trying to use the method that builds it. This is for a server side rendered app built with next.js

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't use state in `getInitialProps`, since it runs before the constructor. Can you provide the rest of your code that shows how you're setting the state you want to use?

Comment: This has nothing to do with NextJS but rather with the understanding of OOP. You cannot use class methods (or `this` reference) inside a `static` method (unless they are also static) simply because, like @estus said, the class has not been initialized.